# Error when trying to Delete Column in CSV with JREPL.BAT

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have the following CSV

```
Account,Screen Alias,Parent,Account Id,Balance,Currency,Logged In,First  Name,Last Name,Email,Begin Date,Details,Transactions,Change Password
100zz,gdgjk,VIL,32541,0.0000,FUN,NO,dfres,juhfdr,jhgfd@hotmail.com,08/23/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
1234567890,123kdd,Ziz,34039,650.0000,FUN,NO,amass,aaa,bloty@gmail.com,11/26/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
12345abc,jackson123,Ziz,34040,0.0000,FUN,NO,aweqwe,uy,hah@gmail.com,11/26/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
123KDD,123KDD,ZizL,34352,0.0000,FUN,NO,JJ,JJJ,123KDD11@GMAIL.COM,12/09/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
17man,17man,ayn,30853,890.0000,FUN,NO,yacoub,ahmed,yaqoub@hotmail.com,04/17/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
1aaaa1,hfjlfj,VIPL,33853,0.0000,FUN,NO,fdshfg,dgfhf,tyduy@hotmail.com,11/17/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
1qqqq1,hjtdkj,VIPL,33668,0.0000,FUN,NO,jhgddx,hgfljg,hdkhf@hotmail.com,11/06/15,Details,Transactions,Change Password
```

I am trying to delete various column to get a csv with the following columns only:

```
Account, Parent, Balance
```

And get rid of the others.

I tried to delete the column `Begin Date` using the JREPL.BAT with following parameters:

```
C:\jrepl "^((?:.*?\B){15}).*?\Begin Date.*?\Begin Date" "$1" /f "c:\macro_vip\Find Customer.csv" /o -"c:\macro_vip\FindCustomProcess.csv"
```

Which does not work (file not found error...)

Any suggestion how to make this work for a single column so that I can repeat the process for all other columns afterwards? Or any way to do the all process in one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,3,5 delims=," %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%a,%%b,%%c
```

Output:

```
Account,Parent,Balance
100zz,VIL,0.0000
1234567890,Ziz,650.0000
12345abc,Ziz,0.0000
123KDD,ZizL,0.0000
17man,ayn,890.0000
1aaaa1,VIPL,0.0000
1qqqq1,VIPL,0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini. With the full csv file I get this:  for /F "tokens=1,3,5 delims=," %%a in (input.txt) do echo %%a,%%b,%%c%%a ........was unexpected at this time.

Comment: The solution above must be placed _in a Batch file_ (as the `@echo off` line suggest). If you want to execute this from the command line, use just one percent-sign instead of a pair in each case...

Comment: Understood! Thanks

Comment: Yes it did !! Thanks !

Comment: In such a case, you may select it (click on its check mark), and also upvote it. This is the way we use here to say "thanks"...